# What security does WebMatrix.WebData use

Tags: c#, .net, webmatrix, websecurity

I work at a company that has been using the same package for our login security for about 8 years. They are currently using WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity

When a user logs in, the code looks like

```
if (!WebSecurity.Login(model.Email, model.Password))
```

My main concern is that we've been using this now for 8 years and I am not able to find much information about this plugin. I am mostly looking to try and find out what encryption it uses and if the encryption is still reliable today.

I tried looking at the documentation docs.microsoft but still no luck

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/webmatrix.webdata.websecurity?view=aspnet-webpages-3.2

Any help / advise on if we should be looking at replacing this or finding out what encryption it uses would be great.